# Showing product attributes in a tooltip

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, tooltip

I am working on a zen cart site and want to display product attributes in a tooltip on listings pages.

The attributes were originally output using

```
<div class="prod_atts">'. $lc_attr .'</div>
```

I replaced this with

```
<div class="prod_atts">'. $lc_attr_tt .'</div>
```

The demo code said to place the following where you want the tooltip:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false" onmouseover="ajax_showTooltip(window.event,\'location/of/file.html\',this);return false"> Your link text here </a>
```

so earlier in the code i added

```
$lc_attr_tt = '<a href="#" onclick="return false" onmouseover="ajax_showTooltip(window.event,'.$lc_attr.',this);return false"> Select required options </a>';
```

The tooltip box displays, but it's blank.

I tried putting $lc_attr instead of '.$lc_attr.' but that didn't work either.

I thought this was going to be simple, but it seems that isn't the case.

What am I missing here?!

Comment: Any errors you get in browser console?

Comment: @leo.fcx POST http://localhost/crowndisplay/location/of/file.html 404 (Not Found)runAJAX @ ajax.js:387ajax_loadContent @ ajax-dynamic-content.js:191ajax_showTooltip @ ajax-tooltip.js:187onmouseover @ index.php?main_page=index&cPath=4:480

Comment: @leo.fcx line 387 is this.xmlhttp.send(this.URLString);

Not sure why it's showing /location/of/file.html when its coded as $lc_attr_tt = '<a href="#" onclick="return false" onmouseover="ajax_showTooltip(window.event,'.$lc_attr.',this);return false"> Select required options </a>';

Comment: Clearly the error says that the html that you want to load is not loading ... I'd recommend inspecting your HTML code using browser dev-tool in order to see what is the exact value assigned to `onmouseover` attribute

Comment: The point is that i haven't asked it to load an html file. I want it to show the content of $lc_attr

Comment: The whole purpose with that particular [ajax tooltip script](http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/?whichScript=ajax-tooltip) is to load some content dynamically via AJAX, you can simply not avoid it. I would  suggest that you find another popover / tooltip script and use that instead.  To me it seems to be really oldschool, and is not being manitained - not worth the effort to get it to work.